# Facebook login, redirection loop

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, authentication

I am including the facebook login into my web page but I have a problem, at first, the code:

```
//FACEBOOK LOGIN
if($_GET['method']=='facebook'){
    require("_facebook.php");
    $session_fb = $facebook->getSession();

    if(!empty($session_fb)) {
        //Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');

        if(!empty($user)){
            //We have an active session, let's check if we have already registered the user
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  ".PREFIX."user WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND oauth_uid = ". $user['id']);
            $ds = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            //If not, let's add it to the database
            if(empty($ds)){
                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."user (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, email) VALUES ('facebook', {$user['id']}, '{$user['name']}', '{$user['email']}')");
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."user WHERE userID = " . mysql_insert_id());
                $ds = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            }
            // this sets variables in the session 
            $_SESSION['oauth_uid'] = $ds['oauth_uid'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $ds['oauth_provider'];

            $_SESSION['ws_auth'] = $ds['userID'].":".$ds['password'];
            $_SESSION['ws_lastlogin'] = $ds['lastlogin'];
            $_SESSION['referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            setcookie("ws_auth", $ds['userID'].":".$ds['password'], time()+($sessionduration*60*60));               
            $login = 1;

        }
        else {
            # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
            die("There was an error.");
        }
    }
    else {

        # There's no active session, let's generate one
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        header("Location: ".$login_url);
    }

    //end fblogin
}
```

The problem is that my code doesn't read the session and makes an infinite loop of redirection :(

Comment: As far as I'm aware getSession isn't a method in the current php-sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ so it will never be populated or are you not using the php-sdk but your own system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TommyBS said, there is no getSession in the current php SDK.

Also, keep in mind this:

1) In your app's configuration on facebook, the App Domains, Website With Facebook Login and (if you need it) App on Facebook / Page Tab URL fields should point to the site your are redirecting.

2) Prepare your app with the [official javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) AND don't forget the channel file.

3) Prepare your app with the proper [P3P headers for facebook iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5609348/173299).